# Sending data from one servlet to other via session

Tags: java, servlets

I am having say a servlet servlet1.java with a session in it like this

```
String mykey = new String("hi");
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute(mykey,  request.getParameter("GName"));
response.sendRedirect("second.html");
```

In second servlet am doing

```
Object OwnerName = request.getSession().getAttribute("mykey");
out.println(OwnerName);
```

But this value retyrn NULL.What can be the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

In the first servlet, you are using the `String` key value `"hi"`. In the second servlet, you are using the `String` key value `"mykey"`.

The `HttpSession` attributes are stored in a `Map`. You need to use the same key to put and retrieve values.

Comment: How ?and i mistakenly pasted wrong code.I edited it please help

Comment: @user3445854 I don't see any difference in the code you edited. `session.setAttribute(mykey, ...)` vs `getSession().getAttribute("mykey")`. See how the keys are different?

Comment: @SotirisDelimanolis I wanted that mykey should hold the value of the field corresponding to GName field in my html file

Comment: @user3445854 Then do that. Why have you created a variable called `mykey` with value `"hi"`?

Comment: @user3445854 You instantiated with the value `"hi"` and then used it as the key to your session attributes. If you want to retrieve the value mapped to that key, you need to use the same key to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The value of MYKEY is "hi".So you'd better use "hi" to get session param in the next page .